# Apache Server does not display the correct website

Tags: debian, apache-2.4, web-server

Hi I'm trying to learn Apache2 with a VPS. So far it's ok, but I can't find the reason for one problem that I face.

I've a website setup in my `/var/www/example.com` folder. I created a config file for that in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com.conf`. Now when I go to `www.example.com` the desired website is displayed. However, if I take the `www.` in the url and just type `example.com` I gives me the Apache default page.

**example.com.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com *example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**apache2.conf**

```
DefaultRuntimeDir ${APACHE_RUN_DIR}
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}
Timeout 300
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 5
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}
HostnameLookups Off
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
LogLevel warn

IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf
Include ports.conf

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

AccessFileName .htaccess

<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>

LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

> ServerAlias [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com) *mydomain.com

to

> ServerAlias  mydomain.com *.mydomain.com

Restart the service.

Perform a nslookup for [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com) and mydomain.com to ensure the ip is the same.

ie
via the console or command prompt, type

nslookup mydomain.com

nslookup [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com)

Ensure that the ip address is the same. If it is not the same, create a domain 'A' record for mydomain.com that is the same as [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com). Aslo look a the error.log for apache.

Comment: I did the changes but it didn't work. The `nslookup` give me the same IP address for both. Please Help

Comment: I looked at your post under ask ubuntu. daily-updates.ga and www.daily-updates.ga do not have the same ip address. daily-updates.ga does not have an ip at all.

Answer (score 0):

Remember to enable your newly created site with `a2ensite example.com`.

If the problem persists, most likely, there is a `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` with [`ServerName`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#servername) either commented out or matching your `example.com`.

> If no `ServerName` is specified, the server attempts to deduce the
> client visible hostname by first asking the operating system for the
> system hostname, and if that fails, performing a reverse lookup on an
> IP address present on the system.

The configuration files are read in alphabetical order and the first `ServerName` or `ServerAlias` matching the `Host` header is used. Because `000-default.conf` is the first match for `example.com`, it gets used instead of your new configuration file `example.com.conf`.

You have a few options:

- Add/edit the `ServerName` in `000-default.conf` to be something else than `example.com`.
- Removing the `000-default.conf` (with `sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf`) makes your `example.com.conf` the default virtual host. However, if you later add a configuration file that comes first in the alphabetical order, it will become the default, so this approach may have unexpected behavior.

Comment: Yeah as you said there was a `ServerName` directive commented out. I removed that completely but still it didnt work. I even disabled the `000-default.conf`with the command but that gives me a `404` error page when I go to the url. Please help.

Comment: Removing the `ServerName` doesn't help at all, because it's already commented out. Instead, you should **add** one with anything else than `example.com`.

Comment: It also sounds like you haven't enabled the site with `a2ensite example.com`.

Answer (score 0):

I actually fixed this by changing some configurations in `example.com.conf` file
I just changed the `ServerName` and `ServerAlias` from

```
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com *.example.com
```

to

```
ServerName www.example.com
ServerAlias example.com
# I removed the wildcart
```

And now the website works fine

Thank you everyone for helping me fix this issue.
Original answer [by emadelbieh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66767416/14004936) in stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already applied some config changes and aren't seeing any results, make sure your browser isn't caching the wrong/old pages.  In Firefox, you can open Dev Tools (F12), then click Network tab, then 'Disable Cache' checkmark, then refresh the page.

Disabling cache can help troubleshoot issues and verify you've set up your sites as expected (I myself just got tripped up over this for an hour, wondering why my Apache configs weren't propagating, only to realize the browser had cached the old page config).  Test your changes with cache disabled!